# ARR throws 404 on adx URLs after rewrite

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, url-rewriting

I have a IIS HA setup [(2 ARR, 2 IIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/achieving-high-availability-and-scalability-arr-and-nlb) that work fine except for .axd ressources.

When going thru ARR any and all .axd return a 404 but when I bypass the ARR (simple DNS record change), the request returns a 200 as expected. Therefore all AJAX and ReportBuilder elements don't load on the page when going thru ARR.

Capturing traffic and looking at logs (website logs & failed request tracing) shows the URL pretty much the same on either ARR or IIS:

Thru ARR

```
2023-08-22 16:10:50 192.168.24.5 GET /WebResource.axd d=lq0PviHnSOFiLL9A9_OGEXaQ7vrP7owj6Gsil0FilogN4XCpuO-ZyR0rHKUEu10SOhO7ChgFq7EcMmy0hf-PVMStIfo8U-QYx43ikiPtIVpdwvD60NrAzxZxcyX-bTPZmF1AUOhi6o5gGfj6aur9LD7VZWW7J7XhXLdmtI9kU5k1&t=636692481600000000 443 - 192.168.30.110 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/116.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://domainhub.domain.com/QuestAfExtClient 404 0 2 26
```

Directly IIS

```
2023-08-22 16:17:30 192.168.24.8 GET /WebResource.axd d=lq0PviHnSOFiLL9A9_OGEXaQ7vrP7owj6Gsil0FilogN4XCpuO-ZyR0rHKUEu10SOhO7ChgFq7EcMmy0hf-PVMStIfo8U-QYx43ikiPtIVpdwvD60NrAzxZxcyX-bTPZmF1AUOhi6o5gGfj6aur9LD7VZWW7J7XhXLdmtI9kU5k1&t=636692481600000000 443 DOMAIN\user 192.168.30.110 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/116.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://domainhub.domain.com/QuestAfExtClient 200 0 0 11
```

I've googled this problem but [most solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms) are to skip .axd files in URL rewrite module so it gets processed without rewrite but this doesn't work here, I think because the .axd needs to be forwarded to the server farm like the rest.

Any suggestions on getting those axd working thru the ARR?

Here are my URL rewrite rules from ARR applicationHost.config:

```
<globalRules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="HTTPS Redirection" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" negate="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="ARR Route to Farm" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://DomainIIS/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
</globalRules>
```

And my webFarm config:

```
<webFarm name="DomainIIS" enabled="true">
    <server address="IIS-01-M.domain.com" enabled="true">
        <applicationRequestRouting weight="100" />
    </server>
    <server address="IIS-02-M.domain.com" enabled="true">
        <applicationRequestRouting weight="1" />
    </server>
    <applicationRequestRouting>
        <protocol includePortInXForwardedFor="false" minResponseBuffer="0">
            <cache enabled="false" queryStringHandling="Preserve" validationInterval="00:00:00" />
        </protocol>
        <healthCheck url="http://iis.domain.com" interval="00:00:05" timeout="00:00:05" statusCodeMatch="200" minServers="1" />
        <affinity useCookie="true" />
        <loadBalancing />
    </applicationRequestRouting>
</webFarm>
```

All these servers are running IIS 10.0 on Win2019.

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-arr-using-frt-rules) to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: @samwu if you read my post you can see that I already did that.

Comment: This is not the information I want, there will be details of the 404 error message in the failed request trace log, can you post it?

Comment: @samwu its doesnt tell much except for the "GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER" tag that shows "[HttpException]: This is an invalid script resource request." which isn't useful at all... but it made we look again at the "URL_CHANGED" tags and I found the problem today. So thanks I guess? haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Looking at the logs I noticed the query string was being striped from the URL after the route to farm rewrite is done. The 404 is therefore expected for AXD ressources.

The UI for URL rewrite "route to farm" does not include the "append query string" option like it does for basic "rewrite" option. The option does appear in the `applicationHost.config` as shown above. However I decided to not modify the config file as it might get overwritten at some point and adjust the rewrite path to `/{R:1}?{QUERY_STRING}` as a workaround. In context, here is the adjusted rule:

```
<rule name="ARR Route to Farm" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://DomainIIS/{R:1}?{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Works great now! AJAX and ReportBuilder works fine :)